# four sentences in Latin, to check

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Are these four sentences in Latin correct?

1. *Peter colorem caeruleum amat.* - Peter likes blue color.
2. *Laura fratri librum dat.* - Laura gives the book to her brother.
3. *Domus meus gilvus est.* - My house is yellow.
4. *Ego Parisis fui ultima septimana.* - I was in Paris last week.

Thank you.

EDIT 1.0: I study alone Latin. Those are my sentences. The translation is from English to Latin. Are they OK?

EDIT 2.0: Corrections:

1. *Peter colorem caeruleum amat.* - Peter likes blue color.
2. *Laura fratri suo librum dat.* - Laura gives the book to her brother.
3. *Domus mea gilva est.* - My house is yellow.
4. *Ego Parisiis fui superiore septimana.* - I was in Paris last week.

Comment: Welcome to latin.SE. I wasn't the downvoter, but it's possible that this was downvoted because it looked like homework, and they felt that was inappropriate. I don't know if the site has any formal policy on homework questions. The help page doesn't seem to address this. If, for example, you're self-studying Latin and need feedback on whether your work is correct, then you should say that.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @BenCrowell: I closed the question for lack of details, but it can be reopened if you elaborate. Which direction are you translating to? Are the translations yours? Where are the sentences from? What makes you doubt the translations? Is there something specific you would like feedback on? A mere list of pairs of sentences isn't enough context.

Comment: I am self studying Latin.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Those are my sentences. I study alone Latin language. I am a beginner. Translation is from English to Latin, as tagged. Thank you.

Comment: @Jan Thanks! Can you edit those details into the question? Please also consider adding details about what the specific question is. The users here typically want to see something more detailed than "is this ok?", so any specific concerns about choice of words or forms or something would be a great addition.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I did the edit.

Comment: I reopened the question.

Answer (score 4):

No:

- *domus, -us* is feminine
- *Parisis* should be *Parisiis* (abl./loc. of *Parisii*)
- *ultima septimana* is the last of all weeks (or the last week of your vacation, or whatever); "last week" = the previous week would be *superiore* (or *proxima*) *septimana*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did the edit 2.0. Are they correct now? Thank you.